# Restkit error Initializing RKCLient

Tags: restkit

I have updated my RestKit installation to 0.10.2.

I have followed the instructions on github, and my project builds perfectly.

However whenever I try to init a RKClient instance with for example: `[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://127.0.0.1"];` I get the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString path]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x324790'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x22f0022 0x1f7acd6 0x22f1cbd 0x2256ed0 0x2256cb2 0x1e23cf 0x1e20df 0x1e1ff4 0x1c4338 0x1c3da3 0x1cb33 0xdfc386 0xdfd274 0xe0c183 0xe0cc38 0xe00634 0x21daef5 0x22c4195 0x2228ff2 0x22278da 0x2226d84 0x2226c9b 0xdfcc65 0xdfe626 0x1b56d 0x2e75 0x1)
```

My project settings:

[image]Is there any more info I need to provide? How can I solve this problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have solved this. The problem was related to Xcode not properly cleaning all the caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try "clientWithBaseURLString" instead, since you're passing an NSString.

Comment: That was also part of the problem. Thanks.